# Assigning the same value to different positions in a list in python

Tags: python, list

Assume that I have the following list in python:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I would like to assign the value 0 to specific positions on the list, for example positions 0, 7 and 9. Could I do something like the following in python without resorting to a loop?

```
x[0,7,9] = 0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There you go:

```
x[0] = x[7] = x[9] = 0
```

Also you can do this with [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) arrays in a more general and flexible fashion:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
>>> indices = [0,7,9]
>>> x[indices] = 0  # or just x[[0,7,9]] = 0
>>> x
array([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 9, 0])
```

but this is probably not what you are looking for, as numpy is a slightly more advanced thing.

Comment: Thank you. I am too spoiled by Matlab, and was looking for a more elegant way to do this than a for loop. But if I can do this with numpy, then I might as well use it. Thanks.

Comment: If you are spoiled by Matlab then `numpy` is _definitely_ the way to go for you. You'll find this link especially useful: http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users.